# Django time reformat

Tags: python, django, validation

I have a pair of time field inputs in my Django forms. I wanted to create the form in a way that allows the user to enter the time in whichever format they would like and the program will reformat to the correct type.

Not sure what is the best way to go.

1. Using Django validation but the user does not get feedback about input.
2. Using html5 time input sounds promising but it has poor support for IE, which users are expected to use.
3. Javascript/jquery but the user can change the Javascript code to bypass client-side validation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should check [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

> Arrow is a Python library that offers a sensible, human-friendly approach to creating, manipulating, formatting and converting dates, times, and timestamps

Comment: To provide immediate user feedback of the input I will need to use Ajax right?